# Karma/Jasmine Expectation error in test with no expectation

Tags: javascript, testing, karma-jasmine

I am using Jasmine on Karma and I am getting the following assertion error on a test that has NO expectations or assertions:

```
1) should do something
     name_of_the_test
     Error: Expected '403c26ca-169d-4682-8baa-3f4b22c041f0' to be null.
    at <Jasmine>
    at /tmp/_karma_webpack_918807/commons.js:1:141508
```

At first, I thought it was something in the assertions/expectations of the test, but there was no `expect` statement on string equality. I removed all expectations/assertions, and it still failed. I even went a step further, and I disabled the entire suite, but the error can still appear on another test. On top of that, I have no assertions in the code itself.

Where can this expectation error come from?

Answer (score 1):

This helped me move forward with my issue: The file on the stack trace `/tmp/_karma_webpack_918807/commons.js:1:141508` is a minified version of **all** your tests. For some weird reason, the error message points to a test that is not really the faulty one. Once I checked the minified version (not very fun trying to read the code in there:)) included in the stack trace, I found the faulty test and I was able to verify the breaking assertion which was caused by a leaking state in between the test runs.

This is might be a bug with Karma and the way they report errors but - unfortunately - it is very misleading